# htaccess allow specific path

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

Currently htaccess is denying all users. I want to only allow the JSON feed from wordpress to be accessible by all users

From the htaccess file's location, the feed url is:

```
./row/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/screen
```

**Question**

From what I understand, this is a "virtual" url created by rewrite rules. Since it's not an actual file and just an endpoint, how do I allow any user to access it?

**Current Attempt**

Here is my current attempt which blocks all users without a password. My `Files` node does nothing.

```
// root folder's .htaccess

AuthUserFile /var/www/domains/dev/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
Require user SecretUser
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All

<Files "row/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/screen">
    Allow from all
</Files>

Satisfy Any
```

**Question**

How can I get the virtual path of `./row/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/screen` to be viewable my all visitors?

** edit **

I've since tried both

```
<Directory row/wordpress/wp-json/v2/>
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Location row/wordpress/wp-json/v2/>
    Allow from All
</Location>
```

With no success, they both cause a 501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of the virtual path (created by wordpress) I had to use `THE_REQUEST` instead:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#^GET /sites/dawna/wordpress/wp-json/#">
        Allow from All
        Satisfy Any
</If>
```

The wordpress redirect uses `wordpress/index.php` so using the `REQUEST_URI` wasn't working because the uri is always `/path/to/wordpress/index.php` making the my if statement useless.

**NOTE**

If you need to support PUT's or other you'll have to add that in. `[A-Z]{3}` or `[A-Z]{3-6}` where the latter will open up to everything.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different approaches to allow a single url, whether it refers to physical file or not, to bypass basic password authentication:

Option 1: Allow a single URL through the password protection:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /var/www/domains/dev/.htpasswd
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} == '/row/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/screen'
Require user SecretUser
```

Option 2: Apply password protection to all requests that don't match a specific URL (this option requires Apache 2.4):

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} != '/row/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/screen'">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Required"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/domains/dev/.htpasswd
    Require user SecretUser
</If>
```